# How to install through pip?

Tags: command-line, permissions, python, sudo

I am new at ubuntu and python too.

While installing different packaged through pip in ubuntu terminal it gives permission denied errors.Ex : `pip3 install numpy`

But when i run same command after running `sudo su` it works perfect.

What is this `sudo su` doing here? And when should i use that command?

What it exactly doing in general term?

Comment: it switches to super user - root. You'll notice `#` at the front instead `$`. It is used to escalate priviledges, which are required for certain tasks.
https://kb.iu.edu/d/amyi

Comment: run using `sudo pip3 install numpy`, basically your current user is not having permissions to write to folders where this package will be installed. So, root privileges are required

Comment: You also could use `easy_install` which allows to install the packages in your `$HOME` directory with `easy_install --user <package-name>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like stated above `sudo su` elevates your privileges and you are basically running the command as root. Just using `sudo` without the `su` will do the same. You can also try running your command as such:

```
pip3 install --user numpy
```

This will install the package to your account and not into the system python environment. I would highly recommend that you read up on [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for installing any additional packages/modules since installing them into your system python environment can muck things up.